# Spring amqp and the correlatinId

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have some doubts about Spring AMQP and the correlationId of an AMQP message. 
I have a Project with two queues (“queue.A” and “queue.B”) and one MessageListener on each:

```
public class ServerHandlerQueueA implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg)


public class ServerHandlerQueueB implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg)
```

In some cases, when I receive a message in the “queue.A”, I have to redirect it to “queue.B”:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(routingkey, msg, new MessagePostProcessor() 
    { …});
```

In all cases I send the response to the client using the following:

```
String routingkey = msg.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo();
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(routingkey, respuesta, new MessagePostProcessor() {
@Override
public Message postProcessMessage(Message msg) throws AmqpException 
{….}
});
```

This is working correctly if I use Spring AMQP on the client side:

```
Object _response = getRabbitOperations().convertSendAndReceive(requestExchange, routingKeyManagement, msg,
new MessagePostProcessor() 
        {
            public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException 
            {….}
        });
```

But If I use the java client (on then client side):

```
RpcClient _rpcClient = new RpcClient(channel, exchangeName, routingKey);
        Response _response = _rpcClient.doCall(new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
                   .contentType("application/json")
                   .deliveryMode(2)
                   .priority(1)
                   .userId("myUser")
                   .appId("MyApp")
                   .replyTo(replyQueueName)
                   .correlationId(corrId)
                   .type("NewOrder")
                   .build(), 
                   messageBodyBytes);
```

I always get a NullPointerException in:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.RpcClient$1.handleDelivery(RpcClient.java:195)
```

I think it's because of the correlationId treatment. When I send a message with Spring AMQP I can see the “spring_listener_return_correlation” and “spring_request_return_correlation” headers in the consumer, but the “correlationId” property is always null.
How can I make it compatible with the pure java client and with Spring AMQP? I am doing something wrong?
Thanks!

**------ EDIT ----------**
I’ve upgraded to Spring AMQP 1.7.4 version.
I send a message like this:

```
Object respuesta = getRabbitOperations().convertSendAndReceive(requestExchange, routingKey, _object, 
            new MessagePostProcessor() 
            {
                public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException 
                {
                    message.getMessageProperties().setUserId(“myUser”);
                    message.getMessageProperties().setType(“myType”);
                    message.getMessageProperties().setAppId("myApp");
                    message.getMessageProperties().setMessageId(counter.incrementAndGet() + "-myType");
                    message.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                    message.getMessageProperties().setRedelivered(false);

                    return message;
                }
            });
```

On the server I have:

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        MessageProperties mp = msg.getMessageProperties();
Gson __gson = new Gson();
                    String _stringMP = __gson.toJson(mp);
                    System.out.println("MessageProperties:\n" + _stringMP);
}
```

And I think the problem is that I always get the correlationId null:

```
{"headers":{"spring_listener_return_correlation":"49bd0a84-9abb-4719-b8a7-8668a4a77f32","spring_request_return_correlation":"32","__TypeId__":"MyType"},"messageId":"32-MyType","appId":"myApp","type":"MyType","replyTo":"amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkABByYWJiaXRATkRFUy1QQzAyAAAsMwAAAAgD.ia4+GgHgoeBnajbHxOgW+w\u003d\u003d","contentType":"application/json","contentEncoding":"UTF-8","contentLength":0,"contentLengthSet":false,"priority":0,"redelivered":false,"receivedExchange":"requestExchange","receivedRoutingKey":"inquiry","receivedUserId":"myUser",
"deliveryTag":5,"deliveryTagSet":true,"messageCount":0,"consumerTag":"amq.ctag-4H_P9CbWYZMML-QsmyaQYQ","consumerQueue":"inquiryQueue","receivedDeliveryMode":"NON_PERSISTENT"}
```

If I use the Java Client I can see the correlationId:

```
{"headers":{},"appId":"XBID","type":"MyOrders","correlationId":[49], ….
```

**------------ EDIT 2 --------------------------------**
I have tried with:

```
getRabbitOperations().convertAndSend(requestExchange, routingKeyInquiry, 
                _object, 
                new MessagePostProcessor() 
                {
                    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException 
                    {
                        message.getMessageProperties().setUserId(“myUser”);
                        message.getMessageProperties().setType(“myType”);
                        message.getMessageProperties().setAppId("myApp");
                        message.getMessageProperties().setMessageId(counter.incrementAndGet() + "-myType");
                        message.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                        message.getMessageProperties().setRedelivered(false);
                        message.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationIdString(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                        return message;
                    }
                });
```

But the "correlationId" is always null at the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using?

The return correlation headers have nothing to do with correlationId; they are used to correlate returned (mandatory) requests and replies.

As long as you copy the `correlationId` and `replyTo` from the `queue.A` message to the `queue.B` message, it should all work ok.

If you can't figure it out, post debug logs from all 3 servers someplace.

**EDIT**

This works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So46316261Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So46316261Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Object reply = this.template.convertSendAndReceive("queue.A", "foo");
        System.out.println(reply);
        Connection conn = this.template.getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
        Channel channel = conn.createChannel(false);
        RpcClient client = new RpcClient(channel, "", "queue.A");
        Response response = client.doCall(new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
                .contentType("text/plain")
                .deliveryMode(2)
                .priority(1)
                .userId("guest")
                .appId("MyApp")
                .replyTo("amq.rabbitmq.reply-to")
                .correlationId("bar")
                .type("NewOrder")
                .build(),
                "foo".getBytes());
        System.out.println(new String(response.getBody()));
        channel.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queueA() {
        return new Queue("queue.A");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queueB() {
        return new Queue("queue.B");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "queue.A")
    public void listen(Message in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        this.template.send("queue.B", in);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "queue.B")
    public String listenB(Message in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        return "FOO";
    }

}


(Body:'foo' MessageProperties [headers={}, correlationId=1, replyTo=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkABByYWJiaXRAbG9jYWxob3N0AAACyAAAAAAB.hp0xZxgVpXcuj9+5QkcOOw==, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=queue.B, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-oanHvT3YyUb_Lajl0gpZSQ, consumerQueue=queue.B])
FOO
(Body:'foo' MessageProperties [headers={}, appId=MyApp, type=NewOrder, correlationId=1, replyTo=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkABByYWJiaXRAbG9jYWxob3N0AAACzAAAAAAB.okm02YXf0s0HdqZynVIn2w==, contentType=text/plain, contentLength=0, priority=1, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=queue.B, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-oanHvT3YyUb_Lajl0gpZSQ, consumerQueue=queue.B])
FOO
```

Comment: I am using the spring-amqp-1.7.2.RELEASE version. The MessageProperties I get on the consumer is:

Comment: {"headers":{"spring_listener_return_correlation":"713072f1-e76d-4776-a985-51fa25d517e5","spring_request_return_correlation":"31","__TypeId__":"java.lang.String"},"messageId":"31-Market","appId":"myApp","type":"Market",
 "replyTo":"amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkABByYWJiaXRATkRFUy1QQzAyAAAIJAAAAAgD.rhnACGcj8ZLXAercnRoD2w\u003d\u003d",

Comment: "contentType":"application/json","contentEncoding":"UTF-8","contentLength":0,"contentLengthSet":false,"priority":0,"redelivered":false,"receivedExchange":"my.requestExchange","receivedRoutingKey":"myRoutingKey","receivedUserId":"myUser","deliveryTag":1,"deliveryTagSet":true,"messageCount":0,"consumerTag":"amq.ctag-sThCqd11pI-FCTJWJObONw","consumerQueue":"my.inquiryQueue","receivedDeliveryMode":"NON_PERSISTENT"}

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question instead and post a comment that you have done so. You also need to show the code in your forwarding message post processor.

Comment: I think the problem has nothing to do with the existence of the two queues. Whether I use "getRabbitOperations (), convertAndSend" or "getRabbitOperations (). ConvertSendAndReceive", the "correlationId" arriving at the server is always null. With the second method I get the headers "spring_listener_return_correlation" and "spring_request_return_correlation". I have edited my question.

Comment: If you use `convertSendAndReceive`, the template will set up the `correlationId`; it won't do that for `convertAndSend` since it's not expecting a reply - you need to copy the `correlationId` from the inbound message on `queue.A`. I need to see debug logs from both sides.

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine for me - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have been doing some testing, and the only way for the correlationId to arrive correctly is with the `message.getMessageProperties () .setCorrelationId` method. I just used `message.getMessageProperties (). SetCorrelationIdString`, and with this the correlationId does not reach the server. Why is this method deprecated?

Comment: Thanks; over the last couple of minor releases (1.6, 1.7) we have been migrating from correlationId being a byte[] to a String; for performance reasons because it caused a double conversion byte[]->String->byte[]. It's deprecated because in 2.0 it is `setCorrelationId(String)` (and `setCorrelationIdString()` is deprecated. It should not matter, however at the application level. I am concerned if that's not the case; please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) with a code example and we'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I've opened an issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-771